# Get original dst. address and port after DST NAT

Tags: c++, sockets, nat

Dears,

Is there any way I can get the original destination address and port of a UDP packet or TCP connection that was redirected to my server application by DST NAT?

It must be protocol (layer 5/6/7) independent.

Or maybe can you suggest me any alternative approach for intercepting packets rather than firewall's DST NAT, that would allow me to get dst. address and port before/after intercepting them? Will PF_RING allow me to do that (I can't think on a way it could prevent packet from going to its original destination)?

**EDIT:** divert socket doesn't solve my problem, mostly because of TCP streams. Still looking for a way to get dst. address and port from before being translated by NAT.

Comment: Do you want the IP address as it was received by the final device, or the IP address before it was translated by the NAT?  If the former, there are some socket options you can use to get at the IP and UDP header. (I can share code if this is the case).   If the latter, probably not unless the NAT is on the same box.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @selbie I want the address and port from before it was translated by the NAT. DST NAT is done on same box where my application runs. I need that because my application needs to intercept a protocol that has no fixed port and can use both TCP and UDP. So I would redirect (DST NAT) all TCP and UDP traffic to the application so it could try match protocol pattern on every packet, intercept it if is the aimed protocol or just forward it to original destination (by the use of `splice()`).

Comment: Interesting problem. Wouldn't the easiest thing be to just modify the code of dst-nat?  Maybe iptables could he used (google for "iptables inspect packet")

Comment: Hm... I just searched about that and looks like iptables matches only exact string. That wouldn't be much useful (and seems like doesn't perform well on heavy load) . Besides that, my application runs on top of BSD and there is no plan from developers to add support for things like that on ipfw. So I came searching about DIVERT sockets. Seems like that's the answer for my question. I'll do further searching about that.